# wp_enqueue_script not displaying script

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This is my first time using wp_enqueue_script for an IDX solution that I am trying to setup on a WordPress site.  My file path is child-theme/js/idx.js

I placed this code in my functions.php file:

```
<?php
function wptuts_scripts_with_jquery()  
{  

    // Register the script like this for a theme:  
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/idx.js',      array( 'jquery' ) );  

// For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );  
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_with_jquery' );  ?>
```

and this code in my idx.js file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://tools.example.com/scripts/postmessage.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$.createDynamicFrame('http://example.example.com', 'http://example.example.com/26611/Carets/search?parentUrl=' + encodeURIComponent( document.location.href ), 'MapSearch');
```

This does nothing. When I use the wptuts_scripts_with_jquery()function in the functions.php with other scripts it seems to work but not with the idx.js script.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to include `<script>` tags inside an external resource but this all wrong - they should only ever contain pure javascript (this is what the browser is already expecting).

Your `idx.js` file should contain only this line: `$.createDynamicFrame(...`

---

Onto the reason why this erroneous file isn't being included though - the array you pass as a parameter when queueing scripts in Wordpress is a list of dependencies.  I'm assuming that since you were trying to include jQuery inside your JS file - then it hasn't been previously loaded by the template?  In which case, **because you haven't *enqueued* jQuery - "custom-script" doesn't have all the required components so it doesn't get pushed onto the page**.

By default wordpress already has a version of jQuery registered - if for CDN preference (or backwards comatibility sake) you need to use a different version then you should [`wp_deregister_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) and re-enqueue it with your desired version.  Otherwise your function should look like the following:

```
function wptuts_scripts_with_jquery(){
  $path = get_template_directory_uri();
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', "{$path}/js/idx.js", array('jquery'));  
}
```

Since nothing exists at `tools.example.com/scripts/postmessage.min.js` I have left this out.  Also note that you can *register* and *enqueue* in a single [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) statement.